# Can I configure a Gmail filter to work only during certain hours?

Tags: gmail-filters

The company I work for uses Gmail for our company mail and I have my phone setup with push mail etc. This is great, but there are some kinds of email I really don't want to know about when I'm not at the office.

Does anyone know of a way I can setup a Gmail filter that only applies during certain hours, so I can filter out work spam when I don't care about it?

Comment: As an alternative, you could filter out work related emails at all times into a different label and archive (remove from inbox), then only check that label when in the office.

Answer (score 4):

No, sorry - GMail filters don't have that feature (yet).